# Sustituir palabras en mayúsculas por un número específico de guiones bajos

Tags: excel, vba

Soy maestro de inglés y tengo una base de datos con alrededor de 2500 oraciones con verbos compuestos los cuales aparecen en mayúsculas.

Ejemplos:

> - This enzyme **ACTS UPON** a limited number of proteins.
> - I was there when David **BALLSED** the presentation **UP**.

Lo que quiero es una fórmula o *VBA* que elimine estas palabras en mayúsculas y en su lugar coloque una cadena de, digamos, 6 guiones bajos por palabra; de modo que el tamaño del guión no dé pistas sobre el número de caracteres del verbo... algo así:

- This enzyme ______ ______ a limited number of proteins.
- I was there when David ______ the presentation ______.

Es importante considerar que letras mayúsculas aisladas como las usadas al inicio de la oración, después de un punto o para nombres propios no deben verse afectadas. ¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo lograr esto?

Comment: Tu base de datos lo tienes en excel ?, es decir, cada oracion esta en una celda de excel?

Answer (score 1):

He visto que la primera solución propuesta no contempla las palabras que empiezan por mayúsculas o la palabra I y hace el reemplazo por el carácter _.
Así que he encontrado una solución que sí que funciona bien en todos los casos que he probado, considerando que las palabras pueden estar separadas por espacios, comas, puntos o punto y coma:

```
Function ReemplazaMayusculasPorSubrayado(strToConvert) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim strDST As String
    Dim isCaps As Boolean

    strToConvert = Replace(strToConvert, ".", " .")
    strToConvert = Replace(strToConvert, ",", " ,")
    strToConvert = Replace(strToConvert, ";", " ;")
    strToConvert = strToConvert + " "
    i = 1
    strDST = ""

    While i < Len(strToConvert)
        j = i
        isCaps = True
        While Mid(strToConvert, j, 1) <> " " And j < Len(strToConvert)
            If Mid(strToConvert, j, 1) = LCase(Mid(strToConvert, j, 1)) Then
                isCaps = False
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Wend
        If isCaps And (Mid(strToConvert, j, 1) = " " Or j = Len(strToConvert)) And j - i > 1 Then
            If Mid(strToConvert, j, 1) = " " Then
                strDST = strDST + String(j - i, "_") + " "
            Else
                strDST = strDST + String(j - i + 1, "_")
            End If
        Else
            strDST = strDST + Mid(strToConvert, i, j - i + 1)
        End If
        i = j + 1

    Wend
    strDST = Replace(strDST, " .", ".")
    strDST = Replace(strDST, " ,", ",")
    strDST = Replace(strDST, " ;", ";")
    strDST = Mid(strDST, 1, Len(strDST) - 1)

    ReemplazaMayusculasPorSubrayado= strDST
End Function
```

Esta función habría que llamarla para todas las celdas de tu Base de Datos en Excel y habría que guardar el resultado en la celda contigua.
Te pongo un ejemplo de como se podría llamar pero tendrías que parametrizar la función para inicializar las variables intFila e intColumna con los valores donde empieza tu rango y dejar la columna de al lado vacía porque la macro te la rellenará:

```
Public Sub ReemplazaTodo()
    Dim intFila As Integer
    Dim intColumna As Integer
    intFila = 1
    intColumna = 1
    While Len(Cells(intFila, intColumna).Value) > 0
        Cells(intFila, intColumna + 1).Value = ReemplazaMayusculasPorSubrayado(Cells(intFila, intColumna).Value)
        intFila = intFila + 1
        DoEvents
    Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Con formulas es muy complicado, por que habría que anidar varios `SUBSTITUTE` por cada letra en mayúscula. Con una función VBA es más sencillo:

```
Function SUBSTUPPER(str) As String

    str_l = LCase(str)
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
       If Mid(str, i, 1) <> Mid(str_l, i, 1) Then
            Mid(str, i, 1) = "_"
        End If
    Next
    SUBSTUPPER = str

End Function
```

Comentarios

- La función recorre la cadena recibida y compara cada caracter con su versión en minúscula, si son distintos reemplaza el mismo.
- Incluir la rutina en un nuevo Módulo de la planilla
- Salvar en un tipo de archivo  permita el uso de macros

Answer (score 0):

Se que es una pregunta antigua pero este es mi aporte:

```
Function OcultarPalabra(str As String, Optional miReemplaso As String = "______")
    'miReemplazo es para que el usuario pueda agregar el valor deseado para reemplazar
    'las palabras en mayúscula, sino lo hace solo quedan los 6 guiones
    Dim str2 As String: str2 = str 'Hacemos una copia de la variable.
    str2 = Replace(str2, ".", "") 'quitamos los puntos
    str2 = Replace(str2, ",", "") 'quitamos las comas
    str2 = Replace(str2, ";", "") 'quitamos los punto y coma
    str2 = Replace(str2, "'", " ") 'quitamos el apostrofo y agregamos un espacio (solo por ser ingles)
    'IMPORTANTE: Como es el idioma ingles no importa las tildes, si fuera español o algún otro idioma
    'eso podría dar al traste con esta función
    Dim i: i = Split(str, " ") 'partimos el resultado en un array
    Dim j
    Dim k
    For Each k In i 'por cada variable (tipo string) guardada en el array, lo guardamos en la variable k
        If isCap(k) Then 'ver función isCap
            str = Replace(str, k, miReemplaso)
        End If
    Next k
    OcultarPalabra = str
End Function

Private Function isCap(ByVal c As String) As Boolean
    Dim Le: Le = Len(c) 'cuanto mide la palabra que estoy enviando. No envío la frase completa solo palabra por palabra
    If Le = 0 Or Le = 1 Then
        isCap = False
        Exit Function ' si la palabra mide cero dígitos o solo un dígito se sale de la función y se devuelve un FALSE
    End If
    Dim V
    Dim B As Boolean: B = False
    Dim i
    For i = 1 To Le
        V = Asc(Right(Left(c, i), 1)) 'consigo el código ASCII de la letra
        If V >= 65 And V <= 90 Then 'si está entre 65 y 90 (A y Z)
            B = True 'defino esta variable
        Else
            B = False 'si aparece solo una minúscula en la palabra defino FALSE
            isCap = B 'devuelvo la variable en la función
            Exit Function 'y salgo de la función
        End If
    Next i
    isCap = B 'si no apareció ninguna minuscula devuelve la variable con TRUE
End Function
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]